Error with the Scanner keyword
When it comes to the Scanner keyword, every time I use it, from getting key inputs to reading files it just chooses to return a annoying error, here's the code that I wrote:
code I wrote
What's the console chooses to return:
The Error it returns
Can someone please help me with this error thanks
